# Can commit throw SQLException?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I am using MySQL Connector/C++. I am not entirely sure if I've to call `sql::Connection::commit()` ***inside*** `try... catch` block or ***after*** the block?
(I couldn't find any information about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commit.html))

Update: Auto-commit is disabled in my code.

Comment: Unless you're invoking "Start transaction" - Queries are auto-commit into the tables.

Comment: Auto-commit is disabled in my code

Comment: As Hanky Panky made an answer. You would use sql::SQLException  in your catch to try to give some debug back to your log or cout. Good Luck on your project bud. :)

Comment: Here's a nice resource for your C++ usage. It's a blog writer for MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html

Comment: Great :) Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRY` ofcourse. You want to `COMMIT` when your `TRY` has succeeded and not when it has failed and has raised an exception you're catching.

In your `CATCH` block you'd use a `ROLLBACK` statement if at all.